# javascript post onclick from php

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have the below script that displays an image based on database results. When a user clicks the image it changes to the new image. The `green_star` indicates that the `$user_id` and `$thedb_id` exist in the database and the `grey_star` indicates they do not exist. What I'm looking for is a way to insert into or delete from the database when the star is clicked. In PHP I know I would just do

```
INCLUDE 'addTo_watchlist.php?user_id=$user_id&thetvdb_id=$thetvdb_id';
```

but JavaScript does not accept post data in that format. Is it possible to do what I'm looking for and if so what is the best route to take?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeIt(id) 
{
    var theImg = document.getElementById(id),
             x = theImg.src.split("/"),
             t = x.length-1,
             y = x[t];

    if(y == 'grey_star.gif')
    {
        theImg.src='./images/green_star.gif'
    }

    if(y == 'green_star.gif')
    {
        theImg.src='./images/grey_star.gif'
    }
}
</script>

<a onclick="changeIt('<?php echo $img_id; ?>')"><img src='<?php echo $image; ?>' name='<?php echo $img_id; ?>' id='<?php echo $img_id; ?>'  border='0' width='50%' /></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is confused at several points; not least because you appear to referring to GET data as POST data (these are two different ways of submitting form data). However, I believe you mean to ask how you can add or remove database entries through JavaScript.

The answer is with **AJAX** (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML).

See here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-ajaxhistory/index.html?ca=dat
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

In this context you would just be making a simple xmlhttprequest in order to trigger a server-side script. So, for example, the JavaScript for adding a film to a watch list would look like this:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// Define the url and the GET data (don't forget to pass the userID and thetvdb_id variables from PHP to javascript)
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Path/addTo_watchlist.php?user_id="+userID+"&thetvdb_id="+thetvdb_id, true);

// Define what happens when the request's readystate changes
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  // Define what happens if the script was successful (similar conditions can be added for other readystates and status codes)
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     // Change was successful
     theImg.src='../images/green_star.gif'
  }
}

// Send the request
xmlhttp.send();
```